# Find a path with alternating colors in a 2-color graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm given a graph G=(V,E) , with a color function C: E-->{red,blue} (e.g an edge can be colored in one of those 2 colors)

I would like to find a path, not necessarily simple (meaning the path is allowed to include an edge or node more than once), which is alternating in colors - that means that every edge's color in the path is different than the previous color in the path.

There aren't any more constraints, but I was told that this could be achieved in linear time.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934717/how-to-find-the-shortest-colored-path

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this in linear time.

Since the path needs to follow edges of alternating colors, there are 3 states that it can be in when it reaches each particular vertex:  either it just traversed a red edge, or it just traversed a blue edge, or it is the very start and hasn't traversed anything yet.

In each state, the edges that can be traversed from the current vertex are different.

If you can make a new, larger graph, with a vertex for every possible (vertex,state) combination, then you can connect those vertexes with uncolored, *directed* edges from each vertex to the vertices you can reach through an original edge of the appropriate color.

Then you can just do a DFS or BFS in the new directed graph to find the path.

NOTE: Making a new graph is useful for understanding, but not strictly necessary - BFS or DFS search algorithms are easily modified to traverse the new graph without actually having to build it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "If you can make a new, large graph, with a vertex for every possible (vertex,state) combination"? There are exponentially many such combinations, aren't there?

Comment: @IVlad: Larger graph, i.e., for each original vertex `v`, you have 2 new ones, `v_red` and `v_blue`, plus an extra `start` vertex.  If the original graph has N vertices, then the new one has 2N+1 vertices.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can define dfs with 2 parameters one for the current node and the other one for the last visited color, so at each node check if the unvisited vertices of that node have an opposite color of the last visited color and go on.

```
dfs(int node,int lastColor)
   for(edge : graph[node])
      if(edge.color != lastColor)
         dfs(edge.pos,edge.color)
```