# How to find the shortest colored path?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Given G=(V,E) Which is every edge has one of these three colors {green,red,blue}.
We call a path "Colored Path" if he has all the three colors in it.

```
    Input: graph G(V,E),weight function w:E->Q+ , colored edges and vertices s .
    output: algorithm that finds for every vertices v, a shortest path from s 
           that is Colored path
```

My solution is to walk through the graph, and count for every vertex the number of colors that the path has. Create 3 copies of the graph named G1,G2,G3

For every v that c(v) = 2 (c is number of colors from s to this path) connect v1 to v2 in the second graph(G2) with edge weight = 0.

for every edge c(v)= 3 connect from v2 (From G2) to v3 (To G3) with edge weight = 0 .

run dijkstra from s to t3 (in G3).

Is my solution Right ?

Comment: Unlike in the 'classical' all-pairs shortest path problem, there might exists vertices `u`, `v` for which there is is no Colored Path from `u` to `v` at all, even if the graph is connected; because of the classes of the edges, the problem also does not seem to decompose easily, as a Colored Path can be decomposed into paths which are not Colored Paths.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed example of your construction?

Comment: The description of your algorithm makes no sense.  What is "for every edge c(v)=3" ?  What is "number of colors from s to this path"?

Comment: I've tried to patch up your algorithm description, but I got stuck halfway trying to figure out what you are actually trying to say. You appear to be creating a second copy of the Graph G2, and then add extra edges between G1 and G2 so that the resulting graph has both G1 and G2 as subgraphs?

Comment: what i mean we remove the edges in G1 that there vertices have the value c(v) = 2 (that mean the path from s to v has 2 different colors) and connect them to the duplicate graph G2.G2 is the same vertices and edges that G1 have except it doesn't have edges between vertices that c(v) = 2 to vertices that have c(u) = 3(vertices that have 3 different colors)  because we connect them to graph G3 and it is also the same vertices and edges of G1. so after we build the graph we use Dijkstra from s that in graph one(G1) to the t in graph 3  (G3).

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934687/find-a-path-with-alternating-colors-in-a-2-color-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look correct to me.

The easiest way is to realize that in normal Dijkstra, there's only one important thing to store in each node, and that's the absolute shortest path length from the root.

With colored paths, you have to store the shortest path length for every color combination. So, for 3 colors, you have to store the shortest red path, the shortest blue path, the shortest green path, as well as the shortest red-blue, red-green and blue-green paths, and finally the shortest red-green-blue path. (Total of 7 color combinations).

Comment: Seems correct, the explanation is quite insightful. Somehow I was expecting the problem to be harder in terms of complexity. To be more concise: Dijkstra's algorithm is for the single-source version, not the all-paris version.